# VueJS : manually trigger an update into observed object/array

Tags: vue.js, observer-pattern

I created a vue object for data reactivity :

```
let vm = new Vue({
  data () {
    return {
      myData: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    myData (value) {
      console.log('changed')
    }
  }
})
```

When I push / edit / delete into `vm.myData`, all is ok, the watcher send me `changed`.

Now, i want to get the `changed` event **only by "touching"** `vm.myData` (without data edition). Can I call an internal method of the observer for this ?

Comment: What do you even mean by "touching"?

Comment: Get the watch firen without changing the observed datas. I mean "touch" is used on file systems for only changing metadatas without the content.

Comment: If you want the logic within your watcher to be fired without changing the data, why not simply abstract it into a method? This way you can call it however you like from your watcher or anywhere else.

Comment: I show the problem with a dead simple example. In my app i need to notify all my vue components watching a vuex state. I can't add a service between them, this will be overkill.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok I have the solution.

We can trigger the `notify()` method from the attached observer :

```
vm.myData.__ob__.dep.notify()
```

I found it from the source when vuejs patch the original methods in order to put the data reactive.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/array.js#L42

Comment: I wonder why you would ever want to do this in this manner. This all seems like one big code smell to me.

Comment: Ok I explain why. I am building a service for Vuex and Laravel Eloquent data sync. When something happens from the backend, data are mutated in frontend, its works fine but the problem is with a cache system : when I know something changes but not really because of the cache (a pages changes), i need to notify readers of the data for refreshing components.

Answer (score 7):

since it's an object(object is passed by reference, not by value), it can be done like this

```
vm.myData = Object.assign({},vm.myData);
```

this create a new object of the exactly same values, but it's a new object so it will trigger watcher.

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/RQeLoM?editors=1011

Comment: We will have some "deep copy" problems i think. And will it be fast enough with a large set of datas ? This is not touching, but replacing all the set.

Comment: depends on the structure of the object. `Object.assign` is not deep clone. it only clones the "1st level" property. See `Warning for Deep Clone` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @Ifnot anyway i don't see other way of touching it. I could delete this answer if it's not what you want

Comment: Nah, keep it :) I will benchmark this and test. I am digging into the vue source right now for a visible method on the observer. Thanks for the answer btw.